# Laravel roles and how to show them

Tags: laravel

Hello there I have a Laravel Question. I need to create a table that shows the following data. Client details ( client name, surname, contact numbers, email address, address). The Client should be in two categories which are  Cooperate and Individual Client. Here is a snippet of what i what i did in my client migration file. I wanted to ask on how best to distinguish between them using roles.

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('client_name');
            $table->string('client_surname');
            $table->smallInteger('phone_number');
            $table->string('email_address');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: try  `composer require spatie/laravel-permission`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column in your table called categorie.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {

       $table->string('categorie');
    });
}
```

You can return the clients in your controller via a simple query, like this:

```
$individual_clients = Client::where('categorie', 'individual')->get();
$cooperate_clients = Client::where('categorie', 'cooperate')->get();
```